# how do i call a function in my program from a shared library

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

i would like to call a function inside my main program from a shared library at runtime without dropping performance

main program:

```cpp
using namespace std;

int b = 2;

// it must be called from the library
void func1(int a) {
    b = b + a;
}

void func2();

int main() {
    func2(); // call "func2" in my shared library
    cout<<"Value: " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

my library:

```cpp
void somefunc(int a);

void func2() {
    func1(5); // Call "func1" in the main program
}
```

Comment: A library is a collection of code that can be used by different programs. Let's say I write a program that uses your library. What is your library supposed to do when it comes to the call to the function from your program? (Keep in mind that I do not have your program on my computer.)

Comment: Do you know about passing function pointers?   When main() invokes func2(), it can pass a function pointer as a parameter.   But this would require changes to your library.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to not define them all in the `main.cpp` file, but instead split them out. Convention has it that you have a `.h` (or `.hpp` if you prefer) header file that has the function declarations (signatures) for anything shared, and then the `.cpp` file contains the definitions (implementations) of them.

That is you'd have:

```
// functions.h

void func1(int a);
void func2();
```

Then move the implementations to the corresponding `functions.cpp`.

Then it's as easy as:

```
#include "functions.h"

func1(0);
```

Although there's many ways to organize your files, I'd recommend not putting a lot of "stuff" in your `main.cpp`, but instead keep that as high-level a possible. Anything remotely complicated should be compartmentalized inside a function and that can be defined in another file.

If you have a "heavy" `main.cpp` then your compile times will get slower and slower as you pile more code into it. When you separate things only the changed dependencies need to get rebuild, so if you have 20 `.cpp` files and only change 1, then you only need to recompile 1.

Comment: no i mean i want to call my function in the main program form ((shared library))

Comment: The main program can import the library and call functions from it. The shared library absolutely cannot import the main program. The main program is not a library. If you need to share something with this shared library you must plan ahead and ensure it's in a sharable form, like a third shared library that both main and this library can import.

Comment: is there anyway to call the main program

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer involves explaining why a `.exe` or executable file is completely different in terms of structure than a `.o` or `.dll` designed to be shared.

Comment: but why visual studio builds .lib with my .exe

Comment: I'm used to it being able to build a `.lib` *or* a `.exe` from the same source files, but the structure of these are different. You can't import functions from a `.exe` the same way you can a dynamic library. Maybe you can, but you'll at least have to narrow down what compiler you need to support.

Comment: i don't what is the different between dynamic library and shared library but i just want to call my function in my main program from a shared library or a dynamic or any library

Comment: Just because you want it really badly doesn't mean it's possible.